# Why error when fill json field properties with type casting?

Tags: laravel

In my seeder of laravel/framework 9.6 I fill json field properties, which is defined in migration :

```
Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->foreignId('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('CASCADE');

    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');

    $table->json('properties')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

And in model app/Models/ProductCategory.php I have :

```
class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'product_categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $casts = [
        'properties' => 'array', // TYPE CASTING
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime'
    ];
```

But I got error :

```
  INFO  Seeding database.


   ErrorException

  Array to string conversion

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php:835
    831▕
    832▕         $result = array_shift($segments);
    833▕
    834▕         foreach ($segments as $segment) {
  ➜ 835▕             $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;
    836▕         }
    837▕
    838▕         return $result;
    839▕     }

      +12 vendor frames
  13  database/seeders/productsWithInitData.php:138
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic()
```

and in seeder file :

```
$properties = $faker->randomElements(['aB','bc','cD','ac','HD'], 2);
ProductCategory::insert([ // ERROR POINTING TO THIS FILE
    'product_id'  => $nextProduct->id,
    'category_id' => $nextCategory->id,
    'properties' => $properties,
]);
```

I can not find why error, seems I made valid type casting...
How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `create()` function instead of `insert()`. The DB facade (query builder) works with `insert()` and the Model eloquent uses the `create()` function.

Refs:

1. Model eloquent with [create()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#inserts).
2. Query builder with [insert()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#insert-statements).